# Search table based on selected mat-autocomplete value in angular 6

Tags: angular, search, angular-material, angular6, mat-autocomplete

I have two mat-autocomplete view in my page. For this i am using this angular material example.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnnnrgqxjmd?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts
This same example i am using.
In the same page i have a table.for which i am displaying data after fetching it from API.

```
<table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let data of reportData>
                    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.idNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.status}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>

              </table>
```

**In one autocomplete view i am populating all Names.
In 2nd autocomplete view i am populating all status.**

I want to search this table based on selected Name and Status from autocomplete.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: Can you post your code in stackblitz